# Two UIScrollViews with one delegate for zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two scrollViews in screen
One scrollView is not calling delegate self, because one scrollView is copy of second scrollView, but have some difference in colors.

For zooming called method

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _images[scrollView.tag];
}
```

but that for only first scrollView.

in scrollViewDidZoom I do like that

```
scrollSecond.zoomScale = scrollFirst.zoomScale;
```

but nothing, because for scrollSecond nothing to zooming.

How I can copy action zoom for second scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

in - (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
you need to return something for both scrollviews.

Also, in - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView you need to set same zoom scale for another scrollView.

I just tested it, when I zoom in on one scrollView, another one zooms in as well.

Here is all the code that you need to make it work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.scrollview1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    self.scrollview2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 320)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollview1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollview2];
    self.scrollview1.delegate = self;
    self.scrollview2.delegate = self;
    self.scrollview1.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    self.scrollview2.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

    self.image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    self.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    self.image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    self.image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

    [self.scrollview1 addSubview:self.image1];
    [self.scrollview2 addSubview:self.image2];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.scrollview2 setZoomScale:self.scrollview1.zoomScale];
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.scrollview1)
        return self.image1;
    else
        return self.image2;
}
```